# Finding strings with 3 letters and 3 numbers(ID's) in large text Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, letter

I need to locate all strings in a large text document which includes 3 letters and 3 numbers such as:
FPV003

But there are hundreds of different strings of such type in-between regular text,

I've tried Regex, but cant get it to work,

How do I locate these 6 charactered strings consisting of 3 random numbers and 3 random letters.

Comment: `I've tried Regex,` what have you tried? `/[A-Z]{3}\d{3}/mg` ?

Comment: *I've tried Regex, but cant get it to work*: What have you tried?! and how it didn't work?!

Answer (score 0):

A regex should be fine here :

```js
var patt = /[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}/g;
var str = "test test AZE123 test test ZER456";

console.log(str.replace(patt, 'it works'));
```

Comment: What if it returns `AZE123` from `0000000AZE123_45` and OP does not expect that?

Comment: Thank you so much :)
So all the strings I need to find comes in order of NUMBERNUMBERNUMBERLETTERLETTERLETTER

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer if it solved your problem. You also answered your own question by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much :)
So all the strings I need to find comes in order of LETTERLETTERLETTERNUMBERNUMBERNUMBER
aaa111
So I think it will find everything with this code;

```
var content = document.getElementById('indhold').innerText;
var UID = content.match(/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}/g)
```